Django MQTT Subscriber save to database and update view
I am creating a live dashboard for race data where timings and other information will be published by multiple clients on a per lap basis.   I am using Mosquitto as my broker.   Guided by this solution I am able to subscribe to the different topics and see the published results.
on_message received from lap_data QOS:0 retain:False - `{"LapCompleted": 32 ... }` 
on_message received from weather_data QOS:0 retain:False - `{ "RelativeHumidity":0.449}

I have completed the channels chat tutorial and have Redis running on WSL.
MQTT is started via the app ready function.  Starting it via the init.py file results in the same error below.
def ready(self):
    if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN'):
        mqtt_client = MqttRemote()
        mqtt_client.start()

To complete the task I need to:
1) add the received messages to the database.
I planned to add records via the on_message_callback but when the models are imported at the top of the MQTTClient.py file I get the following error:
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

So far the best solution I have found is as per this post where the models are imported within the on_message_callback method.
Is this a valid solution or is there something better from a performance pythonic perspective?
2) update the view when a message is recieved.
How can I link on_message_callback with the channels application I built earlier?
Thank you.
